# Can't execute a Java jar file via PHP on Ubuntu

Tags: java, php, ubuntu, nginx

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
exec('java -jar ~/src/epubcheck-*/epubcheck-*.jar -out /var/www/epubcheck-outputs/output.xml /var/www/AChristmasCarol.epub');
```

When I try the command in the terminal it works... But in PHP it does not.

Also I don't even get the java version. But I do get to see the "hey..." so some commands do work, others don't.

I am using NGiNX has my server.

Comment: Just noticed that `~/src/epubcheck-*/epubcheck-*.jar` could be a problem here - `~` is a shortcut for the home directory of the *current user* - so when you run the command yourself, it means `/home/username/src/...`, but when you run it as your webserver's user, it means an entirely different path. Try changing that to the full path of the jar files you want to execute.

Comment: aha, great! glad to help - added the comment to my answer for posterity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [exec](http://php.net/exec) explains that only the last line of the output is returned by exec, so you need to use a parameter to capture the full output.

`java -version` sends its output to `STDERR`, not `STDOUT`, so you need to redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT` if you want to capture the output of that command with PHP.
However, this shouldn't be necessary when you're running an ordinary java program.

```
$output = array();

exec('java -version 2>&1', $output);
print_r($output); // contains the correct output

exec('java -jar myfile.jar', $output);
print_r($output); // should also contain the correct output
```

If this still doesn't work, see my comment on Ibu's answer

Edit: Actual answer, from question comments:

`~/src/epubcheck-*/epubcheck-*.jar` could be a problem here - `~` is a shortcut for the home directory of the *current user* - so when you run the command yourself, it means `/home/username/src/...`, but when you run it as your webserver's user, it means an entirely different path. Try changing that to the full path of the jar files you want to execute.

Answer (score 1):

On the php manual it says that passthru returns void:

> void passthru ( string $command [, int &$return_var ] )

So nothing will be echoed.

Comment: Chances are your apache user doesn't have sufficient privileges to executive java. Try running the command yourself as the apache user and see what happens (eg: `sudo su www-data` `java -version`)

Comment: @Jean-NicolasBoulayDesjardins try running it on the command line

Comment: I have... And it works... It's just PHP that can't execute it.

Comment: @Jean-NicolasBoulayDesjardins Apologies for the assumption, that said nginx behaves in exactly the same way as apache for things like this